# IIS7 Redirect using Rewrite module Issue

Tags: regex, redirect, iis-7.5

I have changed domains and am trying to redirect all requests except for a few URLs. However I can't seem to get it to behave as expected and everything gets redirected - I'm sure it must be something small - any help would be appreciated!

I need for all URLs to be redirected, except anything with the path "auth" or "ipet", as well as file.aspx including its querystring. The rest of olddomain.com should all redirect to newdomain.com.

```
<rule name="Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions trackAllCaptures="false" logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.olddomain\.com" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^file.aspx$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^auth/?" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^ipet/?" negate="true" />
</conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://newdomain.com" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**logicalGrouping="MatchAll"** indicates all conditions must be true to do the redirect. Change **logicalGrouping="MatchAny"** and change match url.

```
<rule name="Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="www\.olddomain\.com" />
<conditions trackAllCaptures="false" logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*?file.aspx$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*?auth/?" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".*?ipet/?" negate="true" />
</conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://newdomain.com" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following.. without `^`:

```
<add input="{URL}" pattern=".*?auth/?" negate="true" />
<add input="{URL}" pattern=".*?ipet/?" negate="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks Karthik, tried it but it still redirects - the regex seems to pass, but it still redirects for some reason. Not sure if there is another IIS redirect setting that I am missing or if it just ignores the "negate".

Comment: @Anton You can always split them in two separate rules, clearly instructing to cancel the redirect in this case.

Comment: @ShellFish - thanks - thats sounds like an idea..Can you possibly show me an answer with what that may look like? I'm brand new at IIS redirects....